# Lower bound on sequence

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I have the following question from my textbook:

> For any integer $k \geq 2$, prove that if $A$ the number of integers $\leq x$ is $y$ such that $y$ can be written as the sum of $k$ many $k$-th powers all $\geq 0$, then $A \leq x/k! + O(x/\sqrt[k]{x})$.

I know I'm meant to show my work, but I have spent so much time on this question and I'm making such disappointingly little progress.

Comment: First try to prove that the number of integers $\leq x$ which can be written as a sum of $k$ *pairwise different* $k$-th powers is at most $x/k!$. Then you will also see how to extend your approach. Hint, this is a combinatorics problem rather than an algebraic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Michal's comment above, such a representation of a given number $n$ as a sum of $k$-many nonnegative $k$-th powers gives us $0 \leq a_1 \leq \cdots \leq a_k \leq n^{1/k} \leq x^{1/k}$ for increasing $a_i$ where $n = \sum_ia_i^2$. Choosing these numbers is equivalent to choosing $k$ elements out of the first $x^{1/k}$ integers -- this can be done in $\binom{\lfloor x^{1/k} \rfloor + 1}{k}$ ways, and there are this many integers $\leq x$ that have this representation. It is easy to show that
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n^k}{k!} + O(n^{k-1}),$$
and so
$$\binom{\lfloor x^{1/k} \rfloor + 1}{k} = \frac{\left(\lfloor x^{1/k} \rfloor + 1\right)^k}{k!} + O\left(\left(\lfloor x^{1/k} \rfloor + 1\right)^{k-1}\right)= \frac{x}{k!} + O\left(x^{1-1/k}\right),$$
as $\lfloor x^{1/k} \rfloor + 1 = x + O(1)$.